# Some Views can be enabled/disabled while others cannot

Tags: android

I have a layout here that has some nested layouts which contain various Views that I want to enable/disable. I thought it would be as straight-forward as calling `setEnabled()` on them but I've found that only works on the `Textviews` and `Switches`. The `Seekbars`, `Togglebuttons`, and `Imagebuttons` don't react to `setEnabled()` programmatically and don't have `android:enabled=""` available to them in XML. What am I missing here?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- ***** Zoom ***** -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL_zoom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_transluscent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_zoomLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Zoom"
            android:textColor="#ff43b7ff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_zoomOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview_zoomLabel"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_out_white_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagebutton_zoomOut"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imagebutton_zoomIn"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar_zoom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_zoomValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textview_zoomPercentageLabel"
            android:text="50" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_zoomPercentageLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_zoomIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textview_zoomValue"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_in_white_24dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--   *****  Focus ***** -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL_focus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RL_zoom"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_transluscent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_focusLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/togglebutton_autofocus"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Focus"
            android:textColor="#ff43b7ff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_focusOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview_focusLabel"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_out_white_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagebutton_focusOut"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imagebutton_focusIn"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar_focus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_focusValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textview_focusPercentageLabel"
            android:text="50" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_focusPercentageLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/togglebutton_autofocus"
            android:text="%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_focusIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textview_focusValue"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_in_white_24dp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/togglebutton_autofocus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:minHeight="1dp"
            android:minWidth="1dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ff43b7ff"
            android:textOff="AF&#10;Off"
            android:textOn="AF&#10;On" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--   *****  Iris ***** -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL_iris"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RL_focus"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_transluscent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_irisLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/togglebutton_autoiris"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Iris"
            android:textColor="#ff43b7ff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_irisOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textview_irisLabel"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_out_white_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagebutton_irisOut"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imagebutton_irisIn"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar_iris"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_irisValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textview_irisPercentageLabel"
            android:text="50" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_irisPercentageLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/togglebutton_autoiris"
            android:text="%" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_irisIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textview_irisValue"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_in_white_24dp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/togglebutton_autoiris"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:minHeight="1dp"
            android:minWidth="1dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ff43b7ff"
            android:textOff="AI&#10;Off"
            android:textOn="AI&#10;On" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--   *****  On/Off ***** -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL_device_tools_on_off"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RL_iris"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_transluscent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_device_power_on_off"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Device Power"
            android:textColor="#ff43b7ff" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_device_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/switch_device_power_on_off"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_white_24dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

While every view has a `setEnabled` method, [the interpretation of the value set through it varies by subclass](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)).

In your case, `TextView`, `Switch`, and `ToggleButton` have logic to respond to this value when it is set. The others don't. In a similar fashion, you're only able to set the `android:enabled` attribute on the these because [it is defined as an attribute that can be used with TextViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_enabled).

If you'd like to have `Seekbar` and `ImageButton` respond to the `setEnabled` value, you can create custom views which extend each of those, override the `setEnabled` method, then implement how you'd like each of these views to react.

Comment: Interesting. Why is it then that there are so many examples on the net of people using `setEnabled` on these `views`?

Comment: I've corrected my previous answer. `ToggleButton` also should respond to the `setEnabled` calls: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ToggleButton.java#150

Is the alpha for your `ToggleButton` not changing when it is disabled?

I'm not particularly sure which examples you might be referring to, but my guess is that they may be taking advantage of `StateListDrawables`. These allow you to display a different drawable depending on the state of the view (our case being enabled/disabled).

Comment: Well, it turns out that `setEnabled()` actually does work on those `views`. I found out when I called `setOnTouchListener()` on the first of three `SeekBars` in a row and now every other `view` reacts to `setEnabled()`. So something about `setOnTouchListener()` is preventing `setEnabled()` from taking effect, but I can't find any info as to why. Have any idea?

Comment: Turns out it's not `setOnTouchListener()` after all. I removed it and the `SeekBars` are still working but now the `Textviews` are not. That was all I changed so I really don't understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out I had a few bugs that I got fixed. I'm posting what I learned because I've not seen it mentioned before, in case someone else runs across this. If you set a custom color to a `TextView` calling `setEnabled()` will not affect the color to make it look disabled. Similarly, for an `ImageView` I set background to `null` and that also makes the the button look like it's not reacting to `setEnabled()`. I'm sure other `Views` have little nuances like this, I just haven't found them yet.